# Numerical solution of Geodesic differential equations with Python

Tags: numerical-analysis, python, ode, scipy, numerical-modelling

I have made a solver based on the [SymPy.diffgeom](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/diffgeom.html) library, where I use [Scipy.Integrate](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/integrate.html) to solve the following system of second order differential equations :

\begin{align}
u'' &+ \Gamma^0_{00}(u')^2 + 2\Gamma^0_{01}u'v' + \Gamma^0_{11}(v')^2 = 0,\\ 
v'' &+ \Gamma^1_{00}(u')^2 + 2\Gamma^1_{01}u'v' + \Gamma^1_{11}(v')^2 = 0,
\end{align}
where $\Gamma^m_{ij}(u(s),v(s))$ is the Christoffel symbol of second kind. The geodesic solution $u = u(s),v = v(s)$ is a curve defined for the interval $s\in[s_0,s_1]$.
These equations can be described as a system of first order differential equations by setting $p = u'$, and $q = v'$ :
\begin{align}
p' &+ \Gamma^0_{00}p^2 + 2\Gamma^0_{01}pq + \Gamma^0_{11}q^2 = 0\\ 
q' &+ \Gamma^1_{00}p^2 + 2\Gamma^1_{01}pq + \Gamma^1_{11}q^2 = 0
\end{align}
with the initial condition given as $u(s_0) = u_0, u'(s_0) = du_0, v(s_0) = 
v_0, v'(s_0) = dv_0$.

Here is a code snippet of my implementation

```
def f(y,s,C,u,v):
    y0 = y[0] # u
    y1 = y[1] # u'
    y2 = y[2] # v
    y3 = y[3] # v'
    dy = np.zeros_like(y)
    dy[0] = y1
    dy[2] = y3

    C = C.subs({u:y0,v:y2}) # Evaluate C for u,v = (u0,v0)

    dy[1] = -C[0,0][0]*dy[0]**2 -\
           2*C[0,0][1]*dy[0]*dy[2] -\
             C[0,1][1]*dy[2]**2
    dy[3] = -C[1,0][0]*dy[0]**2 -\
           2*C[1,0][1]*dy[0]*dy[2] -\
             C[1,1][1]*dy[2]**2
    return dy

def solve(C,u0,s0,s1,ds):
    s = np.arange(s0,s1+ds,ds)
    # The Christoffel symbol of 2nd kind, C, is a function of (u,v)
    from sympy.abc import u,v 
    return sc.odeint(f,u0,s,args=(C,u,v))  # integration method : LSODA
```

I have implemented several generic test cases : torus, sphere, egg carton, and catenoid. However, there seem to be some issue with the solver. On a sphere, for example, the geodesic curve is the great circle (see [reference](http://msemac.redwoods.edu/~darnold/math55/deproj/Sp99/PaulC/mypaper2.pdf)). When I try to find the geodesic curve and plot on a sphere (with same parmaters as [reference](http://msemac.redwoods.edu/~darnold/math55/deproj/Sp99/PaulC/mypaper2.pdf) provided), the curve starts to veer off. There seem to be some sort of numerical instability that is altering the course of the geodesic curve over the interval $s\in[s_0,s_1]$. Is there any way I can make my solver more stable ? I have tried to reduce the step-size of the solver, but that has not made things any better (visually at least...I could probably try to estimate the convergence rate).

[image]

**Edit 1:**

I checked the code for the geodesic curve along the equator, and from pole to pole, and I get no deviation :
[image] 
[image]

**Edit 2:**

I have pasted the test case on the following link : [Geodesic on a sphere](http://pastebin.com/0wTAqW0U).

I forgot to mention this, but I am using the following versions

- SymPy : 0.7.7.dev
- SciPy : 0.16.0

It should now be possible for anyone to reproduce the same results.

Comment: Do you still see this divergence given a geodesic along the equator or one going form pole to pole?

Comment: No deviation at all occurs along the equator or from pole to pole. Will append that to the question.

Comment: Would you mind posting a small complete test case that can be run directly?

Comment: Sure, but it will take me some time to minimize the code for this example only.

Comment: If it is true that start point anywhere leads back to the originating point then seems like you have a bug. I asked you to check out equatorial and polar trajectories because in each of these one of the angular dimensions ($theta$, $phi$) is always zero. Maybe this hints at a coordinate system error somewhere? Hard to say exactly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason the resulting geodesic curve was deviating was because the calculated Christoffel symbol of second kind was incorrect. Using the correct Christoffel symbol :

```
C =  Matrix([[(0, -tan(v)), (0,0)],[(sin(v)*cos(v),0),(0, 0)]])
```

results in the proper output (as displayed in the [reference](http://msemac.redwoods.edu/~darnold/math55/deproj/Sp99/PaulC/mypaper2.pdf)) :

[image]

Now, I suppose I have to figure out why the calculated Christoffel symbol was incorrect. But that is another question.

Comment: Thanks for your well crafted question and answer! My gut feeling for this bug was a coordinate system transformation error. Bug report to the Sympy folks?

Comment: I checked the calculated Christoffel symbol for other coordinate system, and they were calculated correctly. The issue was only with the spherical transformation apparently. I remember now that I had hand coded the symbol. So I introduced the bug. The reason I had to hand code the symbol was because I could not produce it with my code alone. However, I will ask the Sympy google group about why I could not produce the Christoffel symbol for the sphere.

Comment: I finally found the courage to ask the question as to why I get the wrong Christoffel symbol : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33453941/determining-christoffel-symbols-and-curvature-tensors-for-a-flat-sphere-using-sy I will ask at the SymPy google group as well.